# Нужно ли обособлять "скорее" в приведенном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*Где-то внутри я понимаю, что она его не любит. Это другое. Брак, союз двух людей, их сын, в конце концов. Своего рода общепринятые законы жизни: нет, не связывающие двух людей, **а, скорее,** объединяющие их в одном пространстве*. Э. Сафарли, 2021 г.

С одной стороны, "скорее" является **вводным словом** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_671.

Но в значении **необособленного обстоятельства** оно используется чаще, да и при значении вводности тоже иногда не обособляется, например: В спортивной курточке канареечного или скорее попугайного цвета, красные полосы на груди. В. Астафьев.

В приведенном предложении и так много запятых. Так стоит ли обособлять "скорее", если к тому же сопоставление там явно выражено?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я обычно не обособляю слово "скорее", но здесь, как мне кажется, его нужно обособить.

И тогда дополнение к вопросу. Допустим, вот перед нами предмет. **Нужно различать два таких варианта?**

(1) Я не понимаю сущности этого предмета (действия).

(2) Я понимаю его сущность, но затрудняюсь подобрать нужное название. Или это одно и то же?

Чем ***связывать*** отличается от ***объединять***?

Comment: На мой взгляд, тут всё правильно с запятыми. Без них, в отличие от примера из Астафьева, "скорее" читалось бы в значении "быстрее" или в значении "скорее, чем что-то", из-за чего предложение лишалось бы смысла. Ну и в любом равнодопустимом случае выбор всё равно остаётся за автором.

Comment: @Nektoid
А в таком предложении: Это скорее повесть, а не рассказ. Здесь будете обособлять? Варианты похожи.

Comment: понимаете, в чём дело... Правило на Грамоте гласит: *Слово «скорее» не требует постановки знаков препинания, если в предложении подразумевается сопоставление «скорее… чем», «скорее… нежели»*. Но здесь ничего не *подразумевается*, здесь прямым текстом идёт сопоставление. Возможно, я придираюсь, но тем не менее. В Вашем примере я бы тоже поставил запятые, потому что когда читаю это предложение вслух, ясно слышу запятые: паузы и понижение голоса. А вот если скажу просто "Это скорее повесть", то произношу без пауз, т. е. без запятых.

Comment: Не понимаю... В конце концов, нужно же различать наречие в составе предложения,  связанное с его реальным содержанием, и авторскую метку, когда писатель подбирает нужное слово (скорее говоря).  Но все равно, спасибо вам за комментарии